# Which of the Eternals were based on mythological characters?

Tags: marvel, mythology, eternals

Many of the Eternals have names that are very similar to classic mythological characters. This is even called out and explained directly for a couple of them: Thena was the Greek goddess Athena, and to annoy Ikaris, Sprite made up the story of Icarus from Greek mythology who flew to close to the sun. I am guessing that all of the Eternals have a corresponding character from mythology who would be based on them, but I can't figure them all out. Here's a list of the Eternals and my guesses at the corresponding mythological character. If you can explain a link between their powers and the myth, even better.

Sersi: Circe, Greek enchantress
Ikaris: Icarus, Greek who flew too close to the sun
Thena: Athena, Greek goddess of wisdom
Ajak: ?
Sprite: classic fairy
Phastos: Hephaestus, Greek god of the forge
Makkari: ?
Druig: Druid?
Kingo: ?
Gilgamesh: Mesopotamian hero

Bonus for Arishem, Tiamut, Eros and Pip, who shouldn't have influenced Earth mythology but may still be similarly named (Eros clearly is named for the Greek god of love).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sersi: Circe, Greek enchantress
Ikaris: Icarus, Greek who flew too close to the sun
Thena: Athena, Greek goddess of wisdom

Ajak: ?
**Ajax** — a hero of Homer’s *Iliad* & Trojan War.  In Homer's Iliad he is described as of great stature, colossal frame and strongest of all the Achaeans. Ajax was described as fearless, strong and powerful but also with a very high level of combat intelligence. Ajax commands an army wielding a huge shield made of seven cow-hides with a layer of bronze. When the Trojans are on the offensive, he is often seen covering the retreat of the Achaeans. Significantly, Ajax is of the deadliest heroes in the whole poem. In the original Marvel comics, Ajak was a large male. In the MCU, the character was gender-swapped to be a woman, jettisoning the original’s physical features similar to Ajax while retaining the original character’s other skills and abilities, as well as elevating her to be leader (replacing comic Zuras, *Zeus*, in that role) similar to Ajax of myth.
[image: Ajak]

Sprite: classic fairy
Phastos: Hephaestus, Greek god of the forge

Makkari: ?
**Mercury** — Mercury from Roman mythology. The counterpart to the Greek god Hermes, Mercury serves as the god of many things, including communication, financial gain, travelers and, most notably, **speed**. Makkari is another Eternal who was gender-swapped from her initial comic character.

Druig: Druid?
Yes, **druid**.

Kingo: ?
**Quingu** — A Babylonian god and the son of Tiamat, the mother goddess of the earth, as generally described in the *Enûma Elish*, the Babylonian epic of creation. He is killed by Marduk in his slaughter of the gods, but his blood becomes a major facet in the creation of human beings.

Gilgamesh: Mesopotamian hero!

**Arishem**: It is often reported that Kirby was largely inspired by Jewish Kabbalah in his creation of the Celestials, but these sources are second- and third- hand accounts at best. If true, then Arishem would be a phoneme of Hashem, which is another term for God.

**Tiamut**: *See Kingo above*.

Eros: (Eros clearly is named for the Greek god of love)

**Pip**: [Pip was introduced in Marvel Comics Strange Tales 179.](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/22131/strange_tales_1951_179) He wasn’t always a troll but an alien prince who was cursed into appearing like a troll after a night of drinking. As he reveals his origins in the comic, Pip was once Prince Gofern of the planet Laxidazia, in the Dolenz System, in the Milky Way Galaxy. He was originally an alien of the Laxidazian race who enjoyed painting pictures of the night sky. Pip became physically and psychologically mutated into a morally degenerate, stunted, satyr-like form known as a "troll" during a bout of drunkenness brought on by a mutagenic hallucinogenic ale. Pip doesn’t have any particular sidekick, and it’s speculated his whole purpose is to serve as comedic foil to Adam Warlock’s straight man role.